# Create your own Serializable interface to persist the state of the object

Tags: java, serialization

Often it has been asked in interviews how you can create an interface as serializable. The question arises that if we try to check serializable API it does not include any method as it is marker interface, If we try to override the same functionality in user defined interface. If the class instead of implementing serialzable interface creates own serializable interface,will it be achieved? How the same serializable functionality will be implemented? How will it serialize object or persists the state of the object?

Comment: `public interface MyInterface extends java.io.Serializable`?

Comment: Implementing Serializable says only that your type participates in the Java serialization facility.  There are no methods to override, as you point out.  While you can extend Serializable in your own interface, this is often not the best practice, as it obligates every implementer of your API to provide a serialized form which isn't always appropriate.  The List interface, for example, does not extend Serializable.

Comment: @scottb Yes, it's important to emphasise that implementing `Serializable` does **not** make the class serializable, it merely creates an obligation for the author of the class (and all its subclasses).

Comment: @biziclop actually, *yes it does*. "Serializability of a class is enabled by the class implementing the java.io.Serializable interface" from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

Comment: @scottb Yes you are right that it does not guarantee that implementing serializable interface will force the class to behave as serialized. My question is that if my class instead of implementing serializable interface implements user defined serializable interface how this behaviour will be achieved?

Comment: @Harleen: *"if my class instead of implementing serializable interface implements user defined serializable interface how this behaviour will be achieved?"* ... I don't understand your question.  If a developer writes his own serialization facility (or uses a third party one, eg. Jackson), then the implementing class will behave just as the API of the implemented type (interface) specifies.  The behavior would be achieved in an implementation-specific way. And, for the record, implementing (or extending) the `Serializable` interface -will- force the implementations to behave as serializable.

Comment: @kukis You are confusing attempt with success. If serialization isn't enabled for a class, it can't fail. But if you implement `Serializable` when your class can't be serialized (you've got a non-transient, non-serializable field for example), it will fail. It's the class author's job to make sure that doesn't happen.

Comment: @Harleen Could you please rephrase the question to make it clearer what you're asking? Maybe include some mocked up code example too.

Comment: @biziclop My question is that if instead of using Serializable API, I create my own API with same behaviour as Serializable. How it will be achieved? Any user defined class which will implement the newly created API will be able to persist the object? I hope I am clear this time...

Comment: @Harleen So is the question basically: how is serialization implemented in Java?

Comment: @Harleen: The Java Serialization Facility relies heavily upon reflection to determine what instance fields are part of the class's serialized form.  This is a fairly complex process and it isn't something you would want to reinvent without a very good reason.  Third party libraries, such as the JSON serialization facility Jackson, rely on annotations as well as reflection at runtime.  My advice to you is to use an existing serialization tool.  There are very few good reasons to write your own and it would be difficult to justify the time and expense of doing so.

Comment: @scottb Al right I understand there is no point of reinventing the wheel but I want to understand how the JVM understand that the class implementing Serializable interface would be serialized because there is no implementation method for the marker interface.

Comment: The JVM knows to use the serialization facility on any class instance that is written to an `ObjectOutputStream` instance.  The JVM throws an exception   if an attempt is made to write an object to an `ObjectOutputStream` if that object has not implemented the `Serializable` marker interface.  For further info, see the API documentation for `ObjectOutputStream` and `Externalizable`.

Comment: @scottb Thanks for your reply but my question still remains unanswered how JVM will know/understand how to use serialization facility?

Comment: @Harleen: Yes, the question *"how JVM will know/understand how to use serialization facility"* was answered.  The JVM knows to use the serialization facility when an object is written to an instance of `ObjectOutputStream`.  If an attempt is made to write an object to `ObjectOutputStream` whose class does not implement `Serializable`, then a serialization exception is thrown.  The `Serializable` interface does not do the serialization; it is only a marker. Did you look at the API documentation for `ObjectOutputStream`?  Do you understand what Reflection is?

Comment: Thanks @scottb. I think I posted the question with some thing else in mind may be I couldn't convey myself better but you being supportive answered on each comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your custom serialization with implementing readObject() and writeObject() methods. This behavior will override the default serialization behavior.

- Inside writeObject() method, write class attributes using writeXXX methods provided by 
  ObjectOutputStream.
- Inside readObject() method, read class attributes using readXXX methods provided by 
  ObjectInputStream.
- Please note that the sequence of class attributes in read and write methods MUST BE 
  same.

Example:
public class User implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7829136421241571165L;

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int accountNumber;
private Date dateOpened;

public User(String firstName, String lastName, int accountNumber, Date dateOpened) {
    super();
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    this.dateOpened = dateOpened;
}

public User() {
    super();
}

//Setters and Getters

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream aInputStream) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException
{      
    firstName = aInputStream.readUTF();
    lastName = aInputStream.readUTF();
    accountNumber = aInputStream.readInt();
    dateOpened = new Date(aInputStream.readLong());
}

private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream aOutputStream) throws IOException
{
    aOutputStream.writeUTF(firstName);
    aOutputStream.writeUTF(lastName);
    aOutputStream.writeInt(accountNumber);
    aOutputStream.writeLong(dateOpened.getTime());
}
```

}